# Minimum cost to go from a city to another

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have n cities on the number line: 1,2,…,n. Define a function c(i,j) which returns the cost of going from city i to city j, and assume it takes constant time to compute. We want to travel from 1 to n via a set of intermediate cities, but only moving forwards. We can compute the minimum cost of doing this by defining the following recurrence: f(j)=min{1≤i

I am think it as a simpler version of the travelling salesman problem, but I feel that the algorithms for TSP might be too hard for this one...can someone give some advice?

Comment: Is there a strict order to visit the intermediate cities or can we visit them in any order? Also, is the set of intermediate cities every city from 2 to n-1 or can it be some subset of this set?

Answer (score 0):

We can use 'dynamic programming' (basically memorizing a recursion) to solve this problem efficiently.

```
//min_cost[i] denotes min cost to go from city i to city n
set all min_cost[i] to INF

int solve(int i){
    // base case
    if(i==n)
        return 0;

    // if we have already calculated the ans from city i just return it
    if(min_cost[i] != INF)
        return min_cost[i] ;
    else{
        ans = INF;
        for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
            ans = min(ans, c(i,j) + solve(j));
        min_cost[i] = ans;
        return ans;
    }
}
```

Time Complexity - O(n^2)

The brute force way of doing it would be to just try out all possible cities to go to from the current city. So it would look like this,

```
int solve(int i){
    if(i==n)
        return 0;
    ans = INF;      
    for(int j=i+1;j<=n;j++)
        ans = min(ans, c(i,j) + solve(j));
    return ans;
}
```

Wherein if you are at city i you try to find the minimum path by going through all possible paths to see which would be optimal.

But as you can see that min cost answer from a city (say j) is useful for all cities before it (city i < j). So we can optimize the solution using dynamic programming by memorizing the solutions.

Also you can modify the code easily if you want to return back to city 1 after reaching city n.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by creating a graph with `n` vertices (as cities) and adding a directed edge from city `i` to `j` only with the allowed direction.

When we're done creating the graph we can get the minimum path by running Dijkstra algorithm where the source is node `1` and the destination is node `n`.